# ExtJS 4: Ext.grid.Panel constructor throwing exception when config and constructor configs are implemented

Tags: exception, extjs, extjs4, config

I'm trying to pass a custom parameter named "hideButton" to my grid view constructor in Ext JS 4.  The framework is throwing an exception of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'added' of undefined` when I added the "config" and "constructor" configs to my grid view.  The alert message does get called.  This exception gets called after I hit "OK" on the alert dialog.  What is causing this exception?

```
Ext.define('App.view.ExampleGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'view-grid-3',

    config: {   

        hideButton: false
    },

    constructor: function(cfg) {

        alert('called constructor');
        this.initConfig(cfg);
    },
```

...

I'm instantiating the grid view from two different other components using lazy instantiation via the "xtype" config.  Here is the component that needs to hide a button in the grid view by calling the constructor.

```
items: [{
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'view-tree-3',
    width: '40%'
}, {
    region: 'east',
    xtype: 'view-grid-3',
    store: 'GridStore',
    config: {
        hideButton: true
    },
    width: '60%'        
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just say that you can't use `config` blocks with Ext JS 4.x. That is a Touch only feature for the time being.

To add or override config options in derived classes, place the config option right there on the class declaration body:

```
Ext.define('App.view.ExampleGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    hideButton: false,

    ...
});
```

When instantiating do the same with instance config:

```
my grid = new App.view.ExampleGrid({
    hideButton: true // Overriding the default for this instance
});
```

Comment: Ah.  Thanks.  How can I pass a custom value to a view before instantiation?

Comment: Added a couple of examples, see above.

Comment: After using the code you have above, I get this exception: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: hideButton is not defined'

Comment: Nevermind... I had to implement the custom config by doing this: "hidden: this.hideButton" .... all is well!